# All values of $x$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So I just learned about modular arithmetic today and I was solving a system of congruences probably that you saw before.
the statement was

$n ≡ 3\pmod5$

$n ≡ 1\pmod 7$

$n ≡ 6\pmod8$

writing this again as
$$5x + 3 = 7y + 1 = 8z + 6$$
and trying to get a equality
$8z + 6 = 7y + 1$

$8z + 5 = 7y$

so $1z + 5$ is divisible by $7$ which means all solutions for $z$ is $7n' + 2$ this will be the LHS or RHS of the equality

but this time I dont want to solve for z but I want to solve for x to get something more likeable than $3b ≡ 0\pmod5$ and I dont want to use the lcd function or find the first solution and add $8x'$ to it trick

$5x + 3 = 8z + 6$

$5x = 8z + 3$

all solution for $x$ ?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  You appear to be using the same variable ($x$) to represent two different things.  Please edit for clarity.  And to explain why you don't want to use the standard methods to solve the problem.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement) may help (or not).

Comment: $5x = 8z + 3\Longrightarrow 3(z+1) = 5(x-z)\Longrightarrow z +1 \equiv 0 \mod 5$